# How to pass a pointer to a function argument of type fixed size array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

I need to write a lib wrapper. My wrapper function prototype looks like this

```
int my_wrapper(char * configstr);
```

The function to be wrapped looks like this.

```
void my_function(char config[CONFIGSTRSIZE]);
```

I tried to do the following:

```
int my_wrapper(char * configstr)
{
   my_function(configstr);
   return 0;
}
```

This compiles and works but I receive an error. Telling my that the argument is a invalid type.

> discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Is there a way to perform a cast to telling the compiler that the pointer of the calling function always is a pointer of the proper size?

It's more or less impossible to change the interfaces. I thank you for your feedback.

Comment: `void my_function(char config[CONFIGSTRSIZE])` is **identical** to `void my_function(char *config)`.

Comment: You don't need any *wrapper*. Most probably, you're just trying to pass a `const char *`? Show your calling code...

Comment: note that `char ()[size]` and `char *` are **not** the same type. But as it's **impossible** to pass an array, if you write the array type in a function declaration, it's automatically adjusted to the corresponding pointer type. Therefore, the declarations are indeed identical as pointed out by @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: You have posted the wrong code. In the actual code, some function is using `const` qualifiers. Therefore your question cannot be answered in its current state.

Comment: Hy I found a ugly solution (Star)((char ((Star)([CONFIGSTRSIZE])&configstr)

Comment: @Schafwolle and this "solution" invokes **undefined behavior**. Either, if `my_function()` isn't supposed to modify the array, add a `const` to the declaration. Or take a non-const copy of your `const` data and pass that.

Comment: @FelixPalmen soory forgot the * at the beginning

Comment: @Schafwolle the **undefined behavior** has nothing to do with your cast syntax but with the fact you're casting away `const`. The data might be read-only, and without `const`, the compiler will allow write access to it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen with my compile gcc 4.8 the following copiled warning free

Comment: @Schafwolle well, that doesn't make your program *defined*. A cast basically tells the compiler to "*shut up, I know what I'm doing*".

Comment: @FelixPalmen soory just debugged it you are right

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure the code you compiled is the code you posted? Please post a [mcve] and tell us which compiler switches you use to compile and post the complete compiler output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to perform a cast to telling the compiler that the
>   pointer of the calling function always is a pointer of the proper
>   size?

It is not possible in C. Pointers do not have information about the size. You need to pass it as the additional parameter or have this information in the dereferenced object (for example first is the size, or termination value like C strings)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the following function declaration doesn't make much sense, although legal:

```
void my_function(char config[CONFIGSTRSIZE]);
```

It creates the wrong impression that you can somehow *pass an array* (with a fixed size). You can't in C. What actually happens is that C adjusts any array type in a function declaration to a corresponding pointer type, so this declaration ends up to be just

```
void my_function(char *config);
```

You **could** write it like this to emphasize that the pointer passed should point to an array (I prefer not to, but that's a matter of style):

```
void my_function(char config[]);
```

---

Now for your problem, according to the error message you get, you're probably trying to pass a `const`-qualified pointer here. Depending on what `my_function()` is doing, there are two solutions:

1. `my_function()` only **reads** the array. Then you should change the function prototype like this:

   ```
   void my_function(const char *config);
   ```
2. `my_function()` also modifies the array. Then you can't pass some const data there, but you might take a **copy** of your data. Assuming the data is a string, one way to do it would be the following:

   ```
   // having some const char *config
   char *cfgcopy = malloc(strlen(config)+1);

   if (cfgcopy) { // allocation succeeded
       strcpy(cfgcopy, config);
       my_function(cfgcopy);
       // do something with the modified cfgcopy
       free(cfgcopy);
   }
   ```

   Instead of `malloc()`/`strcpy()`, many implementations provide a "shorthand" `strdup()` function you could use. But be aware `strdup()` isn't part of standard C.